# Tkinter adding Images issue

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

so I have looked about but cant find anything that works for me so if I add a image to my first page (log in page) the image will display fine. However if I try and add it to my main page I get the error pyimage 1
Here is the code: (I've tried to remove all the code not needed to shorten it)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Scrollbar, messagebox
import os
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

global appcwd
appcwd = os.getcwd()

class Login_Start(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        main_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="black", height=768, width=1366)
        main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand="true")
        self.geometry("1366x768")

#INSERTING IMAGE HERE
        #path = "{}\\grem.png".format(appcwd)
        #img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        #pic2lab = tk.Label(main_frame, image=img)
        #pic2lab.photo = img
        #pic2lab.pack()

        loginbut = tk.Button(main_frame, width=10, text='Login', command=lambda: Get_Login())
        loginbut.pack()

        def Get_Login():
            validation = True
            if validation:
                root.deiconify()
                top.destroy()
            else:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Information", "The details are either wrong or you need to register")

class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)

        menu_file = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", menu=menu_file)
        menu_file.add_command(label="Main Menu", command=lambda: parent.show_frame(Main_Page))

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        main_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="grey", height=768, width=1366)
        main_frame.pack_propagate(0)
        main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand="true")
        main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.geometry("1366x768")

        self.frames = {}
        pages = (Main_Page, Admin_Page)
        for F in pages: 
            frame = F(main_frame, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(Main_Page)
        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

    def show_frame(self, name):
        frame = self.frames[name]
        frame.tkraise()

class Temp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="black", height=768, width=1366)
        self.main_frame.pack_propagate(0)
        self.main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand="true")
        self.main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.main = tk.LabelFrame(self.main_frame, bg='black')
        self.main.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.21, height=490, width=1330)

class Main_Page(Temp):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Temp.__init__(self, parent)

        mainlabel = tk.Label(self.main, font=("Trebuchet MS Bold", 16), bg="grey", fg="black", text="TEXT")
        mainlabel.pack()
        path = "{}\\grem.png".format(appcwd)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        pic2lab = tk.Label(self.main, image=img)
        pic2lab.photo = img
        pic2lab.pack()
        butbut = tk.Button(self.main, text="press", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Admin_Page))
        butbut.pack()

class Admin_Page(Temp):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Temp.__init__(self, parent)
        hm = tk.Label(self.main, bg="grey", fg='black', text='Admin_Page')
        hm.place(rely=0.02, relx=0.01,)

top = Login_Start()
top.title("main title")
root = App()
root.withdraw()
root.title("main title")
root.mainloop()
```

Like I said works fine in the Login_Start() Class but won't in the Main_Page()

Comment: It is because there are two instances of `Tk()`: `top` and `root`.

Comment: I'm kinda new to tkinter what would the best way be so that it still works off App() and frames

Comment: For your case `Login_Start` should inherit from `Toplevel` instead.  But you need to create `App()` first, then `Login_Start()`.

Comment: think imma just set Login_Start as show_frames first page and just remove the top = part